# On Athena AWS, last update on table?

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, metadata, amazon-athena, data-quality

I try to monitor the data quality on AWS Athena. 
I would like to know how can i find when data have been loaded in a table?

The table hasn't partition and i can't do the partition on this table.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If Partition is not there, its easy as only one file it will be referring.Athena is not basically a table but analytics tool which reads a file in S3. You can browse to file path and get last last_modified. To get location try running SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>

Comment: @DeepakKumar please add answers as actual answers rather than a comment, this helps other users determine which questions are unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

If Partition is not there, its easy as only one file it will be referring.Athena is not basically a table but analytics tool which reads a file in S3. You can browse to file path and get last last_modified. To get location try running

```
     SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>
```